Geometry Proximity working on 3 instances at once (Blender 4.2)?
So I'm having an issue with a Geometry Proximity system that seems to be affecting 3 instances at the same time. Each of the instances is a block of random cubes of varying dimensions, set up so that they don't overlap or leave gaps.
Here's an illustration of the problem:

The original 5x40 block is in the middle. I created 2 instances of it, because I need both copies, to the left and the right, to have the same geometry, and not be randomly reshuffled, so I can animate in a seamless loop.
However, the only way I've found to do that is create instances of the original block and offset them. That creates the problem of the Geometry Proximity system affecting all three instances, however. How can I duplicate the original 5x40 geometry without it reshuffling itself, but won't create this problem with the proximity system?
Trying Duplicate Elements or directly copying the object just reshuffles everything, and so does making a 120x5 stack, which creates animation looping issues. Realizing the instances doesn't affect the proximity sensor affecting the other two either. How do I get the proximity sensor to only "read" one instance at a time, or convert the instances?

"the setup is complicated. Expect a lot of pictures for this one!" - a proper question minimizes the problem to the minimal reproducible example. You're probably missing what instancing is: it's a light-weight object that doesn't store unique mesh data - instead it points to some object with that mesh data. This is why instancing is fast, because mesh data is reused. Some nodes allow you to edit instances, but these work by editing the original the instances point to. And so if they all point to one original, they will be synchronized.

Voting to close as this is effectively a bug hunt request and in its current form won't benefit future visitors of the site. If you believe you can redact the question to fit Blender Stack Exchange format, please use the [Edit] functionality rather than creating a new question, cheers!

I know what instancing is... the real problem is trying to copy the geometry two times without it rearranging itself randomly, so I have something I can loop. That's what the original creator of this technique did - I just expanded it. I always try to document what I do so people understand the context. I'm not sure what a "bug hunt" request is, but if you've any suggestions how to fit the question to the forum I'm happy to do so.

It would probably be easier to reason about if you explained what you were trying to do, instead of describing the implementation.

Got it. I eliminated the explanation of how I made the original 5x40 random cube stack, and just asked the question of how to copy and displace it without it randomly reshuffling itself. Instances make perfect copies, but create the problem that what affects the original affects the instances too. Trying Duplicate Elements or directly copying the object just reshuffles everything, and so does making a 120x5 stack, which creates animation looping issues.  How do I get the proximity sensor to only "read" one instance at a time, or convert the instances? (Realize Instances does not work either).

I guess you should complement "the problem". We don't have any information about "how" or "what" the proximity is doing. It becomes a guessing issue.  Meanwhile, you can add a "realize instances" node, you probably want to "uncheck" the "all" option and chose only one level.

What I will try and do is show at least one node tree, which is the proximity sensor. That's very small and easily looked at. The picture tells the rest of the story. The rest of the node tree I am going to be rebuilding anyway, the original was a kludge because I'm a beginner/intermediate to geonodes.

Could you explain what "reshuffling" is ? Do you mean indices (vertices, edges, faces ?) are mixed between duplicates ?
